# R replication in MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to replicate this code, (from another question in MATLAB),

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190791/what-is-the-empirical-size-of-a-test

The code I am using is,

```
   reps = 1000000;
n = 20;
ACV = erfinv(.975); %AsymptoticCriticalValue
ECV = tinv(.975, n-1); %ExactCriticalValue


for i = 1:reps

    x = normrnd(0, 1, [n,1]);
    tstat = sqrt(n)*mean(x)/std(x);
    DACV(i) = abs(tstat)>ACV;
    DECV(i) = abs(tstat)>ECV;

end

    y = mean(DACV);
    z = mean(DECV);
```

However, I am getting something wrong as the figures don't match up.

The original code in R is:

```
reps <- 100000
DecisionAsymptoticCriticalValue <- DecisionExactCriticalValue <- matrix(NA,reps)
n <- 20
AsymptoticCriticalValue <- qnorm(.975)
ExactCriticalValue <- qt(.975,n-1)

for (i in 1:reps){
  x <- rnorm(n)
  tstat <- sqrt(n)*mean(x)/sd(x)
  DecisionAsymptoticCriticalValue[i] <- (abs(tstat) > AsymptoticCriticalValue)
      DecisionExactCriticalValue[i] <- (abs(tstat) > ExactCriticalValue)
    }
> (mean(DecisionAsymptoticCriticalValue))
[1] 0.06459

> (mean(DecisionExactCriticalValue))
[1] 0.05012
>
```

Comment: The number of reps is different in your code compared to the second one, does this make a difference?

Comment: No this doesnt make a difference its still wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem that you're having is due to the ACV, in matlab you have used the code `erfinv(.975)` but I am guessing that you want the y and z to be close, as in the original question, if you where to change the ACV to 1.96 then you would find the same results as in the above question.

The q norm function in R:

```
# What is the Z-score of the 96th quantile of the normal distribution?
qnorm(.96)
```

credit to: http://seankross.com/notes/dpqr/

So when you change it to 1.96, the critical value from the normal, I think it should work perfectly.

A better answer would tell you how to get 1.96 rather than just putting it in (but I am not sure how to do this).